# Meaning of “chase up” in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The dog **chased** a boy **up** a gum tree for an hour before going away.

**What purpose does “chased up” serve here?** Does that mean that the boy climbed the tree and the dog waited on the ground for an hour before leaving, or the dog and the boy both were on the tree and the chase continued for an hour before the dog went away? Also, **what does “up” in “chased up” mean?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the boy was chased into the tree, and he climbed up.  The dog could not follow, but remained, for an hour, close enough on the ground so that the boy could not get down.

Comment: This is obviously the intended meaning (+1), but for me the original is a little awkward: it technically does say the _chase itself_ lasted an hour.

Comment: What does “up” in “chased up” suggest?

Comment: @AydenFerguson it's not a phrasal verb. It's just "chased" and the place where the boy was chased _to_ is _up a tree_.

Answer (score 1):

Correct parsing:

The dog //chased a boy //up a gum tree// for an hour before going away.

up a gumtree = prepositional phrase

It is odd that it says chased for an hour.

It should have said: The dog chased a boy up a gum tree **and barked** for an hour before going away.

Answer (score 0):

*Up* suggests movement towards a higher position/level.

The chase took place on the ground, and then the boy had to climb up the tree (to catch his breath and escape the dog).

It's not a phrasal verb "chase sb up". *Chase* here means [*drive or cause to go in a specified direction*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/chase) and *up a tree* independently answers a question "where?".

> The dog chased (who?) a boy (where?) *up a tree*.

> Nobody contacted any authorities to chase (who?) him (where?) *off campus*.

> They then chased (who?) the members (where?) *into the courthouse yard*.

As you might notice, the verb, in this meaning, takes two objects, and the pattern is

```
chase <who> <where>
```